# SvelteKit 2 - How to use routes with and without slugs?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I'm using SvelteKit 2 to make a client-side rendered (CSR) progressive web app (PWA).

I'd like to have routes like:

- https://myapp.com/something
- [https://myapp.com/something/[slug]](https://myapp.com/something/%5Bslug%5D)

I've tried using the filesystem based router, where my directory structure looks like this:

```bash
src/routes/something
src/routes/something/[slug]
```

It renders the `/something/[slug]` route fine, but it's not rendering the `/something` route.

I've tried reading the SvelteKit 2 docs and it doesn't appear to cover this case.

Is there a way to make this routing work in SvelteKit 2?

Currently my workaround is to change the route to `/something-else` that doesn't match the slug route.

I should add that the routes work as expected on my local but not when I build and deploy using static adapter.

Answer (score 2):

These routes work just fine if you also have two `+page.svelte` files in the respective locations.
If you intend to just have *one route*, the parameter needs to be made [optional](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/advanced-routing#optional-parameters), and you only have:

```
src/routes/something/[[slug]]/+page.svelte
```

Comment: Yeah I figured as much, but I had multiple `+page.svelte` files at the different nesting levels and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I tested this and it works as expected. If you have a case that does not work, create a **minimal** reproduction and add it to the question. If there actually is a bug, this should be moved to GitHub.

Comment: Thank you @brunnerh I edited the question now to say that it works in my local dev environment, but not when I build and deploy using static adapter. I will do a minimal reproduction as you've suggested.